# Accurate text generation

Tags: text, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, generator, recurrent-neural-network

I have a chatting app that works with predefined messages. The database has about 80 predefined conversations each with 5 possible responses. To clarify, here's an example:

```
Q: "How heavy is a polar bear?"

R1: "Very heavy?"
R2: "Heavy enough to break the ice."
R3: "I don't know. Silly question."
R4: ...
R5: ...
```

Let's say a user will choose **R3: "I don't know. Silly question"**

Then that response will have 5 possible responses, e.g.:

```
R1: "Why is that silly?"
R2: "You're silly!"
R3: "Ugh. I'm done talking to you now."
R4: ...
R5: ...
```

And each of those responses will have 5 possible responses; after which, the conversation will end and a new one will have to be started.

So to recap, I have 80 manually-written conversations, each with 5 possible responses, going 3 layers deep = 10,000 messages total.

**My question:** What would be the most accurate way of automatically generating more conversations such as these using machine learning?

I researched RNN: [Karparthy's RNN post](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).
Although RNN can make new content based on the old, the new content is quite random and nonsensical.

For better understanding of the use of these conversations, please visit [http://getvene.com/](http://getvene.com/s/stackoverflow) and watch the preview video.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? are you just trying to generate realistic sounding conversations, or are you trying to make it actually informative?

Comment: Realistic sounding so it's fun to use is the main goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably start with a generative text model. There is a nice [article](http://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) that uses Python and Keras (you can however use LSTM recurrent neural network also with [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent)). With a good and rich set of training data the algorithm can indeed produce pretty interesting text outputs. As mentioned in the article above, there is a [Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) project where you can find an impressive number of free books for free. That should provide sufficient amount of training data. However, since you probably already played with RNN I will proceed further.

Next thing are the relations between a `question` and possible `responses`. This tells me that there is a certain semantics involved in your conversations. Meaning that it's not random and generated responses should at least try to "fit" into somewhat relevant response. Something like [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) to find a proper categories and topics based on data but in reversed way - based on topic (question) you need to find out at least somehow relevant data (responses). Perhaps some way of splitting the generated text into many parts and then vectorize these parts and use something like [Document Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) algorithm to find the close match? An idea that could also come handy is the [Latent Semantic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) because in fact, from a matrix of words/vectors you need to reduce the matrix as much as you can while still preserving the similarities.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use PPDB http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~ccb/ppdb/ to rephrase your phrases to expand your training data . Check out this paper for example: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P/P16/P16-2.pdf#page=177 you can use similar approach to rephrase each sentence.